# Extract Information From Global.ascx File

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to get the following data from the Application_Error event in the Global.ascx file?

action error came from,
ipaddress error came from,
browser error came from,
browser version error came from,
hostName error came from

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that information is contained in the `Context.Request` property.

```
Context.Request.Url; // /controller/action?foo=bar so up to you to extract the action
Context.Request.UserHostAddress; // 123.456.789.0123
Context.Request.UserAgent // Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
```

And once you are sick of parsing all this crap manually and repeating this code all over again among all your applications you might consider using [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

> hostName error came from

Not sure what you mean here. Isn't that the IP of the client?